# Best practice for encapsulating a parameter that requires multiple interfaces to be implemented

Tags: interfaces, inheritance

I encounter this issue multiple times, but I'm never sure how best to deal with it.

Basically, some methods I write require the implementing object to support multiple interfaces. The example I have in mind is that a table structure needs to be able to `IIterate` over its records and `IStreamable` its content, where

```
IIterate = interface
  procedure First;
  procedure Next;
  property EOF: boolean;
end;

IStreamable = interface // outputs current record in table only
  function StreamOut: TArray<byte>;
  procedure StreamIn(const Input: TArray<byte>);
end;
```

Now I don't think I want to combine these interfaces, as it's rare for methods to require `IStreamable` and not every `IStreamable` class can `IIterate` (my use case has single-record structures too).

The method I am trying to write is

```
CopyTable(InIterate: IIterate; InStreamable: IStreamable; OutIterate:IIterate; OutStreamable:IStreamable);
```

Where the In and Out interfaces must be implemented by the same object. At the moment I'm just asking for one of the interfaces and using a `Supports` call to get the second, though this doesn't give you any compile-time protection. The obvious alternative is to use the above structure and check that both interfaces have the same implementing class, but that looks ugly.

*Is there a better way to work with this kind of problem and get some compile-time safety?*

The implementing language is Delphi (XE2), though I think this is a fairly language agnostic question for languages that don't have multiple inheritance.

Comment: If `CopyTable` requires a parameter to implement two interfaces, then there's a very high change that it's breaking the single responsibility principle and is doing too much. Refactoring that function into two or more smaller, more focused functions should make the problem go away.

Comment: @DavidArno At some point something will need to use both interfaces in conjunction - if there's two simpler classes consuming one each then there will need to be an aggregation of those two classes at some point as the underlying process being performed needs to use both interfaces to complete it's task - it's just abstracting that problem further down the chain

Comment: Are you free to (drastically) modify the `IIterate` interface?

Comment: @MikeNakis Yes, I own it and it's not something exported by the third-party DLL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>First of all, `Iterate` is a lame name for that interface, it should be called `Iterator`, so I will be calling it `Iterator` in this answer, because I am allergic to bad naming.</sup>

You say that you encounter this issue often, and I have to believe you, but I also ought to mention *my* experience, which is that I have rarely, if ever, encountered this need in the last couple of decades that I have been doing OOP.

Usually, when such a need appears to arise, it is an indication that some other aspect of the design needs refactoring.

The first suspect to examine is the `CopyTable()` function: why does it need both an `Iterator` and a `Streamable` for both the source and the destination table?  Why can't it just stream-out the source table to bytes and then stream-in the bytes into the destination table?  And why is it even called `CopyTable` when it is probably just `CopyStreamable()` or `CopyStreamableIterator()` at worse?

If there is nothing that can be done about the function, then the best approach in my opinion is to combine the two interfaces into one.  The name `CopyStreamableIterator()` which describes what the function does immediately tells you that you need a `StreamableIterator` interface which combines `Streamable` and `Iterator`.  There is nothing wrong with that, and you do not even have to make your `Table` class implement that new interface, you can simply implement a `StreamableIteratorDecorator` (see *decorator pattern*) which accepts a `Streamable` and an `Iterator` as constructor parameters and implements the `StreamableIterator` interface by delegating to them.  (Though you will probably just declare your `Table` class as implementing this interface to be done real quick, because your `Table` already implements these methods, so it is good to go.)

<sub>Note: I am presuming that in Delphi, just as in Java and C#, a class may extend only one class but multiple interfaces, and that an interface may also extend multiple interfaces, but even if by any chance this is not true, this functionality can be emulated by aggregating interface implementations into classes and adding to classes and interfaces methods that return sub-interfaces.</sub>

**Amendment**

Thinking about it a bit more, I am realizing that your problem may lie in that ill-named `IIterate` interface.  This interface is trying to cut corners, so it is built in such a way as to force manipulation of the internal state of the underlying (implementing) object.  This causes problems, because it is forcing you to have two separate interfaces, one for altering the internal state of your table to select a row, and another interface for reading/writing the currently selected row.

In a language like C# and Java your table would implement `IIterable<IStreamable>`, and `IIterable<T>` would have just one method, `newIterator() : IIterator<T>`.  In turn, `IIterator<T>` would be defined as follows:

```
IIterator<T> = interface //javaesque
  function Next : T;
  property EOF: boolean;
end;
```

or as follows:

```
IIterator<T> = interface //csharpesque
  function Current : T;
  function HasNext : boolean;
  procedure MoveNext;
end;
```

So, instead of selecting rows, your iteration would be ***yielding*** each row which can then be streamed.  So, you only need to pass an iterator (or better yet an iterable) to your `CopyTable()` function.

Adding rows to the target table can be easily accomplished by implementing a `IConsumer<IStreamable>` interface which simply appends the contents of the `IStreamable` as a new row at the end of the table.

Comment: This is a bit of a case where some people choose an API and others have an API thrust upon them. The API I need to use has a record structure and then another type of structure that basically represents an array of structures. The way that it is written needs a loop of FillStruct/Next calls rather than just blatting the whole structure at once, which seeing that I'm trying to re-use the FillStruct code from the single record case kind of precludes this.

Comment: Making a StreamableIterator interface is one way of doing it, but it in practice it will just add an extra layer to my code that isn't serving much purpose. If I was passing this interface around a lot then it may be worth considering, but for the times it's used `CopyStreamableIterator(GetStreamableIterator(SrcStreamable, SrcIterator), GetStreamableIterator(DestStreamable, DestIterator))` doesn't add enough clarity to warrant the code bloat in this case IMHO.

Comment: Sure, code bloat is an issue.  (But if I recall correctly, Delphi is derived from Pascal, which allows classes and methods to be declared local within a function, so you may be able to contain most of the new code right there where it is being used.  Maybe.)

Comment: You're correct, but I'd still have to have a function that takes two interfaces just to return an interface that could then be passed into a new function. As I'm only really using this structure in one or two places (and it's unlikely to balloon) then I may as well just let the final function take the two interfaces and deal with it rather than spending too much time tying myself in knots trying to make it pretty

Comment: I amended my answer with some more thoughts.

Comment: I realize that this amendment may represent too many modifications to your code, I just added it so as to perhaps present you with a different, possibly better, way of doing things in the future.

Comment: I like what you did with the `<sup>`'s.  When I first saw this answer, my initial reaction to the first paragraph was "what a terrible way to start an answer."  But adding the `<sup>`s made those passages look like [magazine] sidebars without relegating them to footnotes.  Kudos.

Answer (score 1):

Java solved it by simply allowing multiple inheritance for interfaces. What is more interesting it also has some support for `intersection types` (but only for generics). So it is possible to simply write:

```
<T extends InIterate & IStreamable > void something(T argument) {
    InIterate i = argument;
    IStreamable s = argument;
}
```

It is type safe and no cast are required. In Java 8 it is also possible to use such syntax as type for lambda expressions but there still isn't any way to simply declare variable as `InIterate & IStreamable`

Comment: That seems the most obvious solution, unfortunately it's not a solution available to me in my implementing language :-/